# marquee tag is not working with image tag in HTML

Tags: html

**I set marquee tag with an image. But after marquee tag image disappeared. Its not moving. When i remove marquee, image appears.**

```
<div style="margin-top:300px; z-index:100; position:absolute;">


<marquee direction="top" style="margin-top:300px; z-index:1000;

position:absolute;">

        <img src="images/cw.jpg" alt=""></marquee>
 </div>
```

**I want to marquee image. Please help**

Comment: After remove div its working.

Comment: How can i stop moving image after fix time automatically. I have no idea about it. Please give any solution.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the new code and the new problem.

Comment: `<marquee>` is a deprecated HTML tag. Is this 2005 or 2015?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<div style="margin-top:0px; z-index:100; ">


<marquee direction="top" style="margin-top:300px; z-index:1000;

position:absolute;">

        <img src="images/cw.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="80" alt="Natural"></marquee>
 </div>
```

Remove `position:absolute;`
    [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/t1cc1e63/)

**OR**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/t1cc1e63/1/)

Comment: Thankyou for reply.  After remove div its working. How can i stop moving image after fix time automatically. I have no idea about it. Please give any solution.

Comment: Wait a minutes sir @user3526766

Comment: Hi,  Should i wait? Thanx

Comment: Ok, Thankyou for reply

Comment: If u like My answer please click right answer sir @user3526766

Answer (score 0):

give styling to div or img and not marquee... and if you want to change image automatically ... You need to change the `src` content of image tag.. after a specific time interval.
like :

```
$(function() {
    $('#myImage').attr('src', 'image2.gif');
});
```

if you want to stop the marquee ,.,.,. Run a function after a given interval of time ... in which write:

```
document.getElementById('Your_marquee_id').stop();
```

Comment: Thankyou for reply sir. But i dont want change image automatically. I want , when image start moving with marquee tag. After some seconds image has to stop automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a year 2015 version of the old marquee.

To control of long time the image should "scroll", you alter the `animation: marquee 5s linear 3;` property.

Now the image scroll time is set to 5 seconds, 3 times, equals 15 seconds and then it stops.

(text scroll time is set to 3 seconds, 5 times, equals 15 seconds)

```css
.marquee {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-indent: 100%;
    animation: marquee 3s linear 5;
}
.marqueeimg {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    animation: marqueeimg 5s linear 3;
}
.marqueeimg:hover,
.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { text-indent: 80%; }
    100% { text-indent: -60%; }
}
@keyframes marqueeimg {
    0%   { text-indent: 100%; }
    100% { text-indent: -70%; }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">this is a simple marquee using css only tech</p>
<br />
<p class="marqueeimg"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/150/nature/" alt="image"/></p>
```